# How to write custom module for ebtables?

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables, netfilter, ebtables

Basically, I want to write a kernel module that adds a possible filter to ebtables. Then I need to tell ebtables to use my filter on a bridge I have set up.

The reason I need to write my own module is that I want to introduce delay between consecutive packages (for some testing reason). To demonstrate, my network originally has a traffic like this:

```
+++-----------------+++-----------------+++-----------------+++-----------------
```

where `+` shows traffic of a package and `-` means no package on the line. I want to put a bridge in between so that the pattern of the packets would change to this:

```
+----+----+---------+----+----+---------+----+----+---------+----+----+---------
```

This means that I would make sure there would be a certain amount of delay between arrival of each packet.

Now I have written the following simple code which I basically took from linux-source/net/bridge/netfilter/ebt_ip.c:

```
static bool match(const struct sk_buff *skb, const struct xt_match_param *par)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"match called\n");
    return true;  // match everything!
}

static bool check(const struct xt_mtchk_param *par)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"check called\n");
    return true;  // pass everything!
}

static struct xt_match reg __read_mostly = {
    .name = "any",   // I made this up, but I tried also putting ip for example which didn't change anything.
    .revision = 0,
    .family = NFPROTO_BRIDGE,
    .match = match,
    .checkentry = check,
    .matchsize = XT_ALIGN(4),  // don't know what this is, so I just gave it an `int`
    .me = THIS_MODULE
};

int init_module(void)
{
    return xt_register_match(&reg);
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    xt_unregister_match(&reg);
}
```

I successfully load the module. But it's as if it's not there. I'm not getting the logs inside `match` and `check` functions so the bridge is clearly not considering my filter. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried many combinations of loading my filter first, setting up the bridge first or setting ebtables rules first, but none of them change anything.

P.S. The bridge itself works. I am certain that ebtables is also in effect because if I add a policy to drop packages, I don't receive them on the final computer. What I can't figure out is how to tell ebtables to consider my filter also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a kernel module, you also need to write an appropriate plugin for the userspace program, and afterwards, insert a rule invoking it.

If you do not have any options, do not specify any `.matchsize` parameter in `struct xt_match` (equal to specifying 0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am searching for how the user-space program can be written, but with ebtables, all I can find is [this link](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/ebtables-hacking/ebtables-hacking-HOWTO-4.html) which is totally outdated. A lot of stuff with iptables exist, but I'm guessing that would be different from what I need. Can you please guide me to a useful link or a piece of code I could read and try to figure this out?

Comment: Perhaps you will get better results by reading *“Writing Netfilter Modules”* (free pdf) on iptables first, and once sufficient amounts of coffee have been ingested, can go back to ebtables. The ebt howto page you linked looks accurate from a quick start, but remember ebtables is sort of a fork of an old iptables.

Comment: I did as you said. I read the e-book, implemented the module and user shared object. I named the match "any", put xt_any.ko somewhere loadable (also running depmod), put libxt_any.so in /lib/xtables and according to that book everything is fine. Now, no matter how much I search I can't find the command to tell ebtables to use my matching function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The ebtables man page says match extensions are automatically loaded "so there is no need for -m like is needed in iptables". Ok fine, no -m, but whatever combination I try, ebtables is not using my "any" match extension!

Comment: Tried naming them ebt_any.ko and libebt_any.so (put in /lib/ebtables) to no avail

Comment: Alright, I solved it. I will post the whole process as an update tomorrow. It required a mixture of "build inside ebtables source" and "use xtables in the kernel module"

Answer (score 8):

I got this working, not in the most elegant way, but anyway, I am writing it here for a future wanderer:

Let's say your filter name is: "any"

#### User-space plugin

You need headers that are not available outside the ebtables source. So, get the source code, and go to extensions folder. In the Makefile, add `any` to `EXT_FUNC` (that is targets to be built) and write the source file `ebt_any.c` like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include "../include/ebtables_u.h"

/*struct whatever
{
        int a;
};*/

static struct option _any_opts[] =
{
        {"use-any", required_argument, 0, 0},
        {'\0'}
};

static void _any_help(void)
{
        printf("any match options: nothing!\n");
}

static void _any_init(struct ebt_entry_match *match)
{
        printf("any_init\n");
}

static void _any_check(const struct ebt_u_entry *entry, const struct ebt_entry_match *match, const char *name,
        unsigned int hookmask, unsigned int time)
{
        printf("any_check\n");
}

static int _any_parse(int c, char **argv, int argc, const struct ebt_u_entry *entry, unsigned int *flags, struct ebt_entry_match **match)
{
        printf("any_parse: %d\n", c);
        if (c == 0)
                return 1;
        return 0;       // return true for anything
}
        
static int _any_compare(const struct ebt_entry_match *m1, const struct ebt_entry_match *m2)
{
/*      struct whatever *w1 = (struct whatever *)m1->data;
        struct whatever *w2 = (struct whatever *)m2->data;
        if (w1->a != w2->a)
                return 0;*/
        return 1;
}

static void _any_print(const struct ebt_u_entry *entry, const struct ebt_entry_match *match)
{       
        printf("any_print");
}

static struct ebt_u_match _reg = {
        .name           = "any",
//      .size           = sizeof(struct whatever),
        .help           = _any_help,
        .init           = _any_init,
        .parse          = _any_parse,
        .final_check    = _any_check,
        .print          = _any_print,
        .compare        = _any_compare,
        .extra_ops      = _any_opts,
};

void _init(void)
{
        ebt_register_match(&_reg);
}
```

**Note:** if you have data going from user-space to kernel space, write something instead of `struct whatever`. I have commented it out because I am not using anything.

**Note:** even if your program doesn't require an option (such as mine which was supposed to match everything), you need to give an option anyway because that's how ebtables knows to use your filter.

**Note:** some of these functions seem unnecessary, but if you don't write them, you get a "BUG: bad merge" error.

#### Kernel-space module

The kernel-space module is simpler:

```
#include <linux/netfilter/x_tables.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Shahbaz Youssefi");
MODULE_ALIAS("ebt_any");

/*struct whatever
{
        int a;
};*/
    
static bool match(const struct sk_buff *skb, const struct xt_match_param *par)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO"Matching\n");
        return true;
}

static bool check(const struct xt_mtchk_param *par)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO"Checking\n");
        return true;
}

static struct xt_match reg __read_mostly = {
        .name           = "any",
        .match          = match,
//      .matchsize      = sizeof(struct whatever),
        .checkentry     = check,
        .me             = THIS_MODULE
};

int init_module(void)
{       
        int ret = 0;
        printk("Bridge initializing...\n");
        ret = xt_register_match(&reg);
        printk("Bridge initializing...done!\n");
        return ret;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk("Bridge exiting...\n");
        xt_unregister_match(&reg);
        printk("Bridge exiting...done!\n");
}
```

**Note:** if you use `struct whatever` in user-space, you must use the same in kernel-space.

**Note:** unlike user-space plugin that use ebtables headers/functions, the kernel module uses xtables instead!!

Compile the module (fairly standard) and install it for automatic loading. Alternatively, you can `insmod` and `rmmod` the module yourself before adding/after removing ebtables rules.

#### How to make ebtables use your filter

Just add a rule that contains `--use-any some_value` and you're good. For example:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD --use-any 1 -j ACCEPT
```

**Note:** this `--use-any` is the `option` that was given in `ebt_u_match reg.extra_ops` (which was defined in array `_any_opts`) in the user space plugin.